# Why does this code not result in a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I checked the following code in C++ with `valgrind` with `--leak-check=full` and it says no memory leak. Why is that?

```
char *p = new char[256];
delete p;
```

`new[]` should be matched by `delete[]` as far as I know.

Comment: undefined behavior is undefined, including that it could work.

Comment: shouldn't valgrind be smart enough to point this? This is the simplest test I can write for memory leak and I'd expect at least a warning ...

Comment: @DanLincan: no memory is being leaked. A lint-like tool would probably pick it up.

Comment: I compiler on g++4.8 with -Wall and -Wextra on coliru and still no warnings. Strange.

Comment: @DanLincan: you would probably need a *static analyzer* for this, it typically requires more meta-data than most compilers would bother to keep to track this down.

Comment: valgrind memcheck *does* notice this, but does not classify it as a leak.

Comment: Off topic slightly, but in cases like this you should prefer `std::vector<char>` which deals with the destruction for you.

Comment: @MM. If I understand the question correctly, OP asks why valgrind doesn't catch this

Comment: you will catch the warning when you declare `p` and `char[]`

Comment: As I stated in my answer the standard says this is undefined and therefore we can't really reason about the result the exact behavior will depend on the implementation which can vary on many things.

Answer (score 39):

Although it's undefined behaviour as @KillianDS says, the difference probably relates to the fact that both `delete` and `delete[]` free the underlying memory. The point of `delete[]` is that the destructors for each object in the array are called before the memory is freed. Since `char` is a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) and doesn't have a destructor, there isn't any effective difference between the two in this case.

You definitely shouldn't rely on it, however.

Comment: With non-trivial destructor the `delete` will crash, because it stores the count of the elements at the beginning of the array and therefore the pointer is not equal to what the underlying `free` expects and the `free` will raise a fatal assertion. Different compilers and standard C++ libraries do it differently, but AFAIR gcc does this.

Comment: @JanHudec: "will" is way overstating it.  The compiler and the generated code can do whatever they please.  Including appearing to work.

Comment: @cHao: It is *not* overstating (for gcc), because I *looked* at what it generates. See [here](http://ideone.com/lnWBMP) if you don't believe me. (And note, that they can only change this when they increment ABI version, which they didn't for some time.)

Comment: @JanHudec: They can change it whenever they want and still have a conforming implementation; what they've promised they will or won't do is another matter entirely, and has nothing to do with C++ (which promises absolutely nothing).

Comment: @cHao: Yes, they can change it. But when they change it, they must change the ABI version, otherwise they'd break a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 12):

`delete` and `delete[]` will be equal only if the `p` points to basic data types, such as char or int.

If `p` points to an object array, the result will be different. Try the code below:

```
class T {
public:
    T() { cout << "constructor" << endl; }
    ~T() { cout << "destructor" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    const int NUM = 3;
    T* p1 = new T[NUM];

    cout << p1 << endl;
    //  delete[] p1;
    delete p1;

    T* p2 = new T[NUM];
    cout << p2 << endl;
    delete[] p2;
}
```

By using `delete[]` all the destructors of T in the array will be invoked. By using `delete` only `p[0]`'s destructor will be invoked.

Comment: Or it could crash and immolate your PC, it's undefined behavior after all. Depending on the implementation `new[]` could use the first 8 bytes of the allocated buffer to store the number of elements, and then return an offset within the buffer; in this case a `delete` would pass the offseted address to `free`, which could result in `free` not finding the corresponding buffer...

Comment: @MatthieuM.: IIRC when compiling with gcc it _will_ crash (and immolate your PC), because the number of elements is written at the beginning of the array and therefore the pointer is shifted compared to what the underlying `malloc()` returned. It will _not_ crash when compiling with MSVC++, which apparently derives the count from the general block metadata. The difference being that microsoft has one library for C and C++, so the C++ relies on implementation details of the C one while GNU stdlibc++ honours layering and only relies on public interface of the C library.

Answer (score 11):

When I try this, valgrind reports:

```
==22707== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==22707==    at 0x4C2B59C: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22707==    by 0x40066D: main (in /home/andrew/stackoverflow/memtest)
==22707==  Address 0x5a1a040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 256 alloc'd
==22707==    at 0x4C2C037: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22707==    by 0x40065D: main (in /home/andrew/stackoverflow/memtest)
```

It's not really a memory leak, but valgrind does notice the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Because it's undefined behavior. In your case, `delete` may do the work of `delete []` in your compiler, but it may not work on another machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so we can not reason about its behavior. If we look at the draft C++ standard section `3.7.4.2` *Deallocation functions*, paragraph *3* says (*emphasis mine*):

> [...] Otherwise, the **behavior is undefined if the value supplied to operator delete(void*) in the standard library is not one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either operator new(std::size_t) or operator new(std::size_t, conststd::nothrow_t&) in the standard library**, and the behavior is undefined if the value supplied to operator delete[] (void*) in the standard library is not one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either operator new[] (std::size_t) or operator new[] (std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&) in the
>   standard library.

The actual details are going to be [implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984) and could vary greatly.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `delete` and `delete []` is that the compiler adds code to call the destructor for the deleting objects. Say something like this:

```
    class A
    {
        int a;
        public:
            ...
            ~A() { cout<<"D'tor"; }
    };

    a=new A[23];
    delete [] a;
```

This `delete [] a;` is transformed to something like,

```
   for (int i=0; i<23; i++)
   {
       a[i].A::~A();
   }
   std::delete a;
```

So, for your case since it is an built in datatype there is no destructor to call. So, it transformed as,

```
   std::delete a;
```

which intern calls the `free()` to deallocate the memory. That's the reason that you are not getting any leak. Since memory allocated is completely deallocated using `free()` in g++.

But best practice is that you have to use `delete []` version if you use `new []`.